# How to add an Icon in a angular select directive?

Tags: angularjs, select, glyphicons

I have a simple angular select to show many options and I need to include a glyphicon for each row.

```
<select name="service" required class="form-control" ng-change="selectServiceType(selectedServiceType)" ng-model="selectedServiceType" ng-options="type.name | translate for type in eqTypes">
</select>
```

What is the best way to add glyphicon to angular select?

Comment: Please provide expected results. There are no rows in a `select` and it is not clear what you want to do with icon

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select, the functionality you want is easily achieved with it. Other suggestion would be to build your own directive on top of ng-options.